# Unexpected token limit in JPA

Tags: mysql, jpa

Whenever i'm using LIMIT in JPA query exceptionn is Thrown.can any one suggest me alternative way to filter the record on the basis of their rowNum or ronCount.

```
Select a from EmployeeBo where a.batchId=:'127'and LIMIT :startPonit,:endPoint,
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `LIMIT` in JPA Named Query, but you can restrict records up to a row count by using `setMaxResult();`

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Query#setFirstResult()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setFirstResult(int)) and [Query#setMaxResults()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setMaxResults(int)) for this.

Comment: Hey I am facing same issue,Predrag Maric ,if i set any integer value in setFirstResult(5),like i did it always give records from 0 position ,i don't know why its happning i think this is JPA Flaw.

Comment: @Shardendu If you print out the generated SQL, is first result applied?

Comment: I don't think ii is applied

Comment: @Shardendu Which database are you using? Did you set database dialect to match your database?

Comment: These propeteis i configured <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
      <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true" />
  <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />